# mysql sort table and get row position

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've got a problem in mysql, I have a table of ID and nubmer ... somthing like that

```
ID -------- number
3  -------- 340
1  -------- 10
12 -------- 23
```

And now I would like to selecet by ID, let's say ID=3 and is there a way of saying what is the position of this row in sorted table? In this case, ID = 3 would have first position, cuase of highest value in number. ID=12 would have second position ... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @row_number:=0;
select * from 
  (select ID, @row_number:=@row_number+1 from your_table order by number desc) 
   as row_to_return 
where ID=3;
```

The above query can be change to replace `ID` to anything you need.
However, for simple usage, `ORDER BY number DESC` is better and optimized.

Comment: Thanks ajreal, but for some reasson, with this it doesn't show any error, but neither eny output ... of course I've replaced "your_table" and id value .. with generated one, probably my fault,

Comment: @Martin - the above need to execute twice, if you are using PHP, has to break into two queries

Comment: $ajreal --- thank you so much! You are absolutly right, you saved my day! thansk, thnaks and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning the resultset via PHP, you can use PHP to determine the position of the value '3' within the array for the ID field by using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Or change your SQL as follows:

```
select
@rownumber:=1+@rownumber as 'rownumber',
id_field, number_field
from yourtable, (SELECT @rownumber:=0) rownumber order by number_field DESC
```

This will add an additional column 'rownumber' which provides the number of each row

Comment: Thnak you, this works, but only If I'd like to print all the results with cycle like while, or foreach in PHP.

Comment: What I want thou is to find the position of the row in ordered table and print only this value ... don't want take big usage on database if you know what I mean :(

Comment: The 'rownumber' will give you the position

Comment: Ergo- yes, it gives me number fo the row, but if I modify it to select only one row with "WHERE id=#id#" it will tell me that the row number is "1", even thou, there are enteries with higher value that should be on first position ... and with 1000 I don't want them to be all in array

Answer (score 0):

try this query if usefull.

```
SELECT ID,number FROM table_name ORDER BY number DESC;
```

Thanks.