# mysql join issue

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select * from new_table;
+-------------+
| idnew_table |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           2 |
+-------------+

mysql> select * from second_table;
+----------------+--------+
| idsecond_table | second |
+----------------+--------+
|            100 |      1 |
|            150 |      1 |
|            200 |      2 |
+----------------+--------+

mysql> select * from third;
+---------+-------+
| idthird | third |
+---------+-------+
|     500 |     1 |
|     600 |     2 |
+---------+-------+
```

and i need to join it to one, like this

```
+-----+-----+--------+------+------------+
| tid | sid | secsec | thid | thirdthird |
+-----+-----+--------+------+------------+
|   1 | 100 |      1 |  500 |          1 |
|   1 | 150 |      1 | null |       null |
|   2 | 200 |      2 |  600 |          2 |
+-----+-----+--------+------+------------+
```

I'm trying this query

```
select 
t.idnew_table as tid,
sec.idsecond_table as sid ,
sec.second as secsec,
th.idthird as thid,
th.third as thirdthird
from
new_table t
join second_table sec on sec.second = t.idnew_table
join third th on th.third = t.idnew_table
```

but it repeats rows from third table like this

```
+-----+-----+--------+------+------------+
| tid | sid | secsec | thid | thirdthird |
+-----+-----+--------+------+------------+
|   1 | 100 |      1 |  500 |          1 |
|   1 | 150 |      1 |  500 |          1 |
|   2 | 200 |      2 |  600 |          2 |
+-----+-----+--------+------+------------+
```

so i need your advice

Comment: how are u expecting the sql enging to differentiate those rows? u need a different id system to get the result you want.

Comment: Why did you create this db structure? Couldn't you create a single table with three columns (for the first, the second and the third)?

Comment: From what I understand of your post the query is doing exactly as it needs to and there isn't a way to do what you are wanting.

Comment: i cant create a single table with three columns. this query is for "view"

Comment: @Paul: Why the `500` row from the 3rd table is related to the `100` one from the 2nd table and not to the `150` one?

Comment: What would happen if there was another `(180,1)` row in the 2nd table?

Comment: Or a `(550,1)` row in the 3rd table?

Comment: @ypercube the 500 row from 3rd table is related to the 1 from the 1st table, but not to 100 or 150 from 2nd table

Comment: with (180,1) in 2nd table we would have one more null subrow from third table in result table. with (550,1) row in the 3rd table we wouldn't have any null subrow in result table

Comment: OK. What you want is a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of the second and third table, based in rownumbers (which there are not in the tables) and then a (usual) INNER JOIN to the first table. It's possible but not with standard SQL (at least in MYSQL that doesn't provide windowing functions).

Comment: See this question to get an idea how to show rownumbers in a table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377095/mysql-sort-table-and-get-row-position

Comment: This question is more close to what you want to achieve, as you want row numbers for every group (id): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493389/mysql-select-counter-group-by

Answer (score 0):

From your comments and the data you provided, I guess that you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of the second and third table, based in rownumbers and ids (`second_table.second` and `third_table.third`) and then a (usual) `INNER JOIN` to the first table.

Unforunately no row numbers exist in the tables and MYSQL doesn't provide windowing functions. Therefore it's possible but with something horrible like this:

```
SELECT
    fulljoin.*
FROM new_table t
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
         COALESCE(second,third) AS idnew_table
       , idsecond_table AS sid
       , second AS secsec
       , idthird AS thid
       , third AS thirdthird
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        @rn := if(@g = second, @rn+1, 1) AS rownumber
      , second
      , idsecond_table
      , @g := second
    FROM
        ( select @g:=null, @rn:=0 ) AS initvars
    CROSS JOIN
        second_table
    ORDER BY
        second
      , idsecond_table
    ) AS grp2
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        @rn := if(@g = third, @rn+1, 1) AS rownumber
      , third
      , idthird
      , @g := third
    FROM
        ( select @g:=null, @rn:=0 ) AS initvars
    CROSS JOIN
        third_table
    ORDER BY
        third
      , idthird
    ) AS grp3
    ON grp2.second = grp3.third
    AND grp2.rownumber = grp3.rownumber

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         COALESCE(second,third) AS idnew_table
       , idsecond_table AS sid
       , second AS secsec
       , idthird AS thid
       , third AS thirdthird
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        @rn := if(@g = second, @rn+1, 1) AS rownumber
      , second
      , idsecond_table
      , @g := second
    FROM
        ( select @g:=null, @rn:=0 ) AS initvars
    CROSS JOIN
        second_table
    ORDER BY
        second
      , idsecond_table
    ) AS grp2
    RIGHT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        @rn := if(@g = third, @rn+1, 1) AS rownumber
      , third
      , idthird
      , @g := third
    FROM
        ( select @g:=null, @rn:=0 ) AS initvars
    CROSS JOIN
        third_table
    ORDER BY
        third
      , idthird
    ) AS grp3
    ON grp2.second = grp3.third
    AND grp2.rownumber = grp3.rownumber
    WHERE grp2.second IS NULL
    ) AS fulljoin
ON fulljoin.idnew_table = t.idnew_table
;
```